# ArcGis for Android Beginner

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I have the following activity called activity_esri_map:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.stevecortis.wmsdemo.MainActivity">

<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/arcMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapoptions.MapType="Topo"
    mapoptions.ZoomLevel="13"
    mapoptions.center="33.666354, -117.903557" />
```

This is called from the MainActivity:

```
final MapOptions mStreetsBasemap = new MapOptions(MapOptions.MapType.STREETS);

private MapView arcMapView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esri_map);
    arcMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.arcMap);
    arcMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap);
}
```

From the MainActivity I haven't been able to change anything from tha map. It seems like the findViewById(R.id.arcMap) It is not being assigned to the arcMapView.

I have tried to change other things such as Scale, and nothing seems to affect the actual MapView.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the MapView's MapOptions twice, first in the layout through  the `mapoptions.` parameter settings then in code with `arcMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap);`.  With both of these set you should see the Topo Basemap which is coming from your layout View.  You should remove `arcMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap);` from your source.  If you want the Streets basemap set it in you layout view, e.g. `mapoptions.MapType="STREETS"`.

Comment: But I need to be able to change it programmatically, and I thought that with arcMapView.setMapOptions(mStreetsBasemap); I was doing it correctly.

Comment: Take a look at the Basemaps (https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/Basemaps) sample to see how to work with MapOptions in your layout view and programmatically.